# pandas I want to traverse a column of data, and then count the result from 0 to the current row

Tags: python, pandas

i hava pandas.DataFrame like

```py
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3
```

I want to get the result like

```py
a   resulta
a1   nan
a2   a2 ÷ max([a1,a2])
a3   a3 ÷ max([a1,a2,a3])
a4   a4 ÷ max([a1,a2,a3,a4])
.
.
an   an ÷ max[a1,a2,a3...an]
```

how can i do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is not clear what you are asking. Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and make clear what the expected result should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `cummax` method of pandas ([doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cummax.html)):

```
df["resulta"] = df["a"] + df["a"].cummax()
```

if df is

```
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  2
```

you would get

```
   a  resulta
0  1        2
1  2        4
2  3        6
3  2        5
```